# Insert a value by row and column based using jQuery

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns, rows

I have an array with rows and columns as well values for the corresponding rows and columns.
Now I need to insert those values into my table.

The array which I have as below:

```
Array
(
     [cols] => Array
        (
            [0] => c1
            [1] => c2
            [2] => c3
        )

    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => R1
            [1] => R2
            [2] => R3
            [3] => R4
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 3
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 3
            [9] => 1
            [10] => 2
            [11] => 3
        )

)
```

The table structure what I need is:

```
id | row | column | value
--------------------------
1  | r1  |  c1    |  1
2  | r1  |  c2    |  2
3  | r1  |  c3    |  3
4  | r2  |  c1    |  1
5  | r2  |  c2    |  2
6  | r2  |  c3    |  3
7  | r3  |  c1    |  1
8  | r3  |  c2    |  2
9  | r3  |  c3    |  3
etc..
```

If I try this in for and for each loop the looping continuously looping that number of times..

Please help me to rid out this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$i = 0;
$table = array();

foreach ( $array['rows'] AS $row ) {
    foreach ( $array['cols'] AS $col ) {
        $table['id'] = $i + 1;
        $table['row'] = $row;
        $table['column'] = $col;
        $table['value'] = $array['name'][$i];
    }

}
```